# Почему в школе не изучается пассивный залог?

Tags: общие-вопросы

О существовании пассивного залога мы узнаем при изучении иностранного языка и при этом не подозреваем, что такой залог есть и в русском языке тоже. Но почему?

Почему мы думаем, что школьники способны усвоить разные науки на очень высоком уровне (интегральное исчисление, циклы Карно и т.д.), но только русская грамматика должна даваться в упрощенном виде (одно и то же  как в младших, так  и в старших классах)?

И это не риторический вопрос, хочется знать настоящую причину. Залоги - это не единственная закрытая тема, есть и другие. Никто не предлагает изучать историческую грамматику  (это действительно сложная наука), но об основах  современного родного языка хотелось бы иметь более ясное представление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, это всё же риторический вопрос, потому что здесь на него не ответят.

```
                             хочется знать настоящую причину.
```

Настоящую причину могут назвать только разработчики школьных программ и учебников,а мы можем только предполагать. Видимо,разработчики считают, что для базового уровня знаний, каковой даётся в школе, достаточно в морфологии глагола знать в рамках категории залога о возвратности, переходности(на переходности основано спряжение глаголов с приставкой обес-/обез-: обессилеть самому, обессилить кого-нибудь) и о таких понятиях, как субъект и объект (совсем недавно и этого не было). Сейчас хоть даются разные значения постфикса -СЯ, правда,без термина "среде-возвратный залог"( "собственно-возвратный", "взаимно-возвратный","обще-возвратный","косвенно-возвратный", "безобъектно-возвратный").Думаю, это верно, средний ученик вряд ли это освоит. Учитель иностранного языка, говоря о залогах, соотносит активный залог с действительным в русском языке ( о нём дети знают по причастиям-особой форме глагола), пассивный - со страдательным. Так называемые межпредметные связи.

Получается,что знания о залогах в школе всё-таки даются, вернее о морфологических и синтаксических средствах выражения залоговых значений:морфологические средства - суффикс -СЯ, суффиксы действительных и страдательных причастий, наличие объекта и отсутствие его, различие форм и значения сущ., управляемых глаголом; синтаксические средства - использование подлежащего в роли субъекта и объекта(лыжники отправляются в поход; Письма отправляются по почте; Посылки отправляются экспедитором). Может, этого и достаточно? Речь ведь идёт только о терминах. Умный учитель назовёт и термин, чтобы приблизиться к европейскому образованию.

Comment: При разборе мы бодро указываем, что  глагол возвратный, потому что он имеет частицу СЯ. Вот и все знания о возвратности. Еще дети умеют СЯ относить к основе глагола (прерывистая линия). Их научили так делать, а они ни о чем не спрашивали (не проявляли почему-то интереса).  А потом вдруг появляются новые понятия: постфикс  СЯ, оказывается,  бывает словообразовательным или формообразующим, он входит в основу или не входит, а что это значит -  и лингвисты не все разбираются, а нужно с детей спрашивать.

Comment: Получается, что всё-таки надо было сказать хотя бы коротко о двух разных залогах: возвратном и активном/пассивном, только говорить надо было раньше, а не перед экзаменами. В общем, хотели как лучше (не утруждать школьников лишними знаниями), а получилось как  всегда (всё и всех запутали).  И все это является результатом  фрагментарного изложения знаний: не от простого к сложному, а по принципу «немного этого и чуть-чуть того.

Comment: А тут встретился мне  еще интересный разбор в школьном словаре: "Люди будут возвращаться". Основа словоформы - возвращаться, основа слова - возвраща_ся, то есть ТЬ  тоже может включаться или не включаться в основу. Это тоже проходят в школе? Такие грамматические тонкости действительно развивают у школьников чувство языка? И неужели на это « простое и ясное понятие» надо тратить драгоценные школьные часы?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, от пассивного залога в школьном курсе остались пассивные причастия, это больше, чем ничего. А причины, видимо, исторического характера: сложно разбирать пассив без обращения если не прямо к церковнославянскому языку и его грамматическому аппарату, то в любом случае к текстам, считавшимся излишними для советских школьников по идеологическим причинам, вроде аввакумовых писаний или переписки Грозного с Курбским. Единственный древнерусский текст, изучаемый в школе  - Слово о полку Игореве, да и то в адаптированном виде.

Comment: В моей вполне средней школе провинциального города в 90-е годы и Аввакума и переписку Грозного с Курбским читали. Аввакума в классе 6-м на уроке литературы, а Переписку в 7-м на уроках истории. Оба текста были представлены в хрестоматии или учебнике, Аввакум даже с ятями.

Comment: Дом строится - это пассивный залог?

Comment: Дом строится - пасивный залог. А вообще, да, странно. При изучении английского, например, залог проходят. В школе, например, мы проходили залог в  армянском языке ( причем армянский основной язык был, а не иностранный).

Answer (score 1):

Основная цель изучения русского языка в школе  - это научить школьников более-менее грамотно излагать свои мысли. Носители русского языка, как правило, почти все граматические нормы усваивают на бессознательном уровне в процессе общения, поэтому теоретические аспекты граматики школьникам преподают только в том объёме в котором это необходимо, чтобы правильно писать и расставлять знаки пунктуации.

Если вы считаете, что понимание, что такое пасивный залог поможет улучшить орфографию, пунктуацию или стилистику в речи и/или текстах школьников, то можете разработать методику, где будет прописано как всё это реализовать и попробуйте её испытать.

Comment: На бессознательном уровне усваивают грамматику маленькие дети,  грамматика же позволяет нам правильно строить предложения, избегать речевых ошибок. Только зная грамматические основы, мы можем сделать свою речь  грамотной, ясной, точной, выразительной. Не так велик объём необходимых грамматических знаний, но и его мы  стараемся урезать. Вот почему не изучается порядок слов, актуальное членение предложения, расстановка логических ударений?

Comment: «Ученик решает задачу, задача легко решается» – вот и вся формула пассивного залога, который следует отличать от залога возвратного. И почему бы нам не научиться сравнивать языки (ну хотя бы русский с английским), чтобы понять, как все их английские времена и все залоги выглядят в русском варианте. Но нам это не нужно, и в то же время мы непозволительно много времени тратим на различные грамматические разборы, которые мало что дают практическому знанию языка.

Comment: @Vera незнание того, что такое пассивный залог мешает его употреблять? Грамматику на бессознательном уровне усваивают все носители языка: и маленькие дети, и взрослые мужи. У маленьких детей все мысли умещаются в простые предложения, а вот взрослому такого примитива уже не хватает, приходится осваивать новые высоты языка. Что касается межяхыковых связей, замечательно! Только надо кооперироваться с учителем английского и все в классе должны этот английский изучать, т. е. такое де-факто возможно лишь в специализированных школах.

Comment: Я тоже не считаю, что излишнее теоретизирование в школе способствует усвоению родного языка. Оно нужнее для изучения языка как иностранного, когда у обучаемых нет интуитивных ориентиров. Польза этого в одном: если в будущем кто-то захочет специализироваться в русской филологии, у него будет начальное представление о методах анализа речи. Синтезировать же родную речь по ещё более усложнённым правилам - дело сомнительное. Полезнее ориентировать учащихся на примеры хорошей речи и на объяснения, сводящие вопрос к простым и ясным понятиям, а не к всё новым обобщающим терминам и правилам.

Comment: Иначе можно приучить человека до седин обращаться к справочникам, прежде чем что-то сказать - он утратит способность находить грамматические ориентиры внутри себя. 
Проводить ли параллели с другими языками? Ни в коем случае, если речь идёт о языках других групп. В них другой порядок слов при тех же акцентах и том же типе предложения, другой буквальный смысл идиом, есть типы предложений, не похожих на наши (топикализация и т.п.). Вред русскому языку и без того наносит журналистика, подхватывающая из английского буквальные выражения "он является частью этого", "он тот, который может" и пр.

Comment: Vera , я не согласна с Вашим утверждением, что  "мы непозволительно много времени тратим на различные грамматические разборы, которые мало что дают практическому знанию языка". Вот разборы как раз многое дают - и фонетический, и морфологический, и синтаксический. Они помогают видеть структуру слова и предложения, а значит, помогают выбрать верную орфографию и пунктуацию.

Comment: Вы пишете:"Вот почему не изучается порядок слов, актуальное членение предложения, расстановка логических ударений?" Почему не изучается? Изучается. Вы давно программу в руках держали? Инверсию уже в 5 классе знают, логическое ударение тоже, а актуальное членение у Бабайцевой  в упрощённом виде: данное и новое.

Comment: Людмила, я не против грамматических разборов, я против  их формальной сущности. Разборы  существуют сами по себе, не влияя на практическое знание языка

Comment: О сравнительном языкознании.  У на три времени, а в английском их двенадцать. Еще у них есть пассивный и активный залог. При этом мы переводим текст с одного языка на другой.  Неужели хотя бы в общих чертах  учитель не должен рассказать, как это делается? Неужели ученики не спрашивают его об этом? Как  же нам тогда воспитать творческое и думающее поколение?