# Превратить активный залог в пассивный

Tags: глаголы, английский-язык

Рассмотрим конструкцию:
Объект глагол субъект.

Как изменить глагол, чтобы подлежащее стало объектом действия, а не субъектом? В английском это делается мановением руки, а вот русский что-то буксует на половине примеров:

> Я побил Васю => Я был побит Васей.
>
> Я учил Васю => Я был обучаем Васей. Я обучался Васей.
>
> Я обучил Васю => Я был обучен Васей. Я обучился Васей.
>
> Я имею друга => Я имеюсь у друга.

А теперь примеры, где русский буксует:

> Я бью Васю => Я ??? Васей
>
> Я полюбил Васю => Я ??? Васей
>
> Прямая стала кривой => Прямая ??? кривой

Почему русский в отличие от английского не всегда способен превращать актив в пассив?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106480/discussion-on-question-by-user190920-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос, конечно, ужасно сформулирован...
Нету в русской грамматике пассива. "От слова совсем". 
Это, собственно, и есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Что в русском есть — так это страдательный залог, который, конечно, тоже своего рода "пассив", но совсем не такой универсальный, как в английском.

> Почему русский в отличии от английского не всегда способен превращать актив в пассив?

Вообще-то, в такой постановке это ваши проблемы, а не проблемы русского языка. 
Да еще это "почему" в вопросе... Потому что гладиолус.
Можно ставить вопрос, почему у вас не получилось — это еще более или менее осмысленно.
Вот на этот вопрос я и попытаюсь ответить.

Судя по вашим примерам, вы пытаетесь (не всегда аккуратно, кстати) выдать за пассив конструкцию "быть + страдательное причастие".
Неудивительно, что вы уперлись. Такая конструкция в русском имеет очень ограниченное применение. Во-первых, практически исключено использование в настоящем времени. Вы тут, правда не мудрствуя лукаво, заменяете страдательный залог возвратным. Но это тоже очень ограниченно по возможностям. Не всякий глагол с возвратной частицей имеет нужное для такого приема значение. "Я кусаюсь собакой" — это что-то совсем из другой оперы.

Во-вторых. Упомянутый прием почти не используется для глаголов несовершенного вида. Прямого грамматического запрета тут нет, но уж очень неестественно звучат фразы типа "Я был кусаем собакой".

Ну и самое главное. Страдательные причастия в русском (в отличие от английских "пассивных") образуются совершенно нерегулярно, масса глаголов их вообще не имеет, за единичными (и спорными!) исключениями их нет у глаголов непереходных. Естественно, что конструкция, которую вы назвали "пассивом", для таких глаголов исключена. Я сплю, я ухожу, я радуюсь... — пассив (как его ни понимай) для таких глаголов исключен.

Резюме (очень кратко). Пассива в русском языке нет. Это положение грамматики, и его трудно обойти чисто грамматическими средствами. Более всего на звание пассива претендует неопределенно-личная конструкция типа "меня покусали". Это не то, о чем вы спрашивали. В реальности же замена на "пассив" (по смыслу) достигается просто сменой подлежащего и прямого дополнения: собака покусала меня — я покусан собакой. Но какой-то востребованности в таких формах в русском языке нет. Всё это можно выразить и другими, более присущими русскому языку, конструкциями.

Comment: А как же "я обрадован"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ничего против "обрадован" не имею. Поясните, почему о нем вспомнили. Я не вижу, чему именно в моем тексте противоречит его существование.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Во многом с вами согласен. В некоторых моментах конечно есть что возразить, но это к делу мало относится. Насчет существования пассива в русском вот тут https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416408 эксперты не могут взять в толк почему школьников не учат пассивному залогу. Ответ на свой вопрос(ну вы докопались там до конкретных слов, можно поправить) я хотел бы видеть примерно таким и вы его почти озвучили - "Потому что пассива особо нет, а вместо этого есть безличные предложения (а в английском с этим хуже, поэтому там есть пассив)"

Comment: В ответ вот на что я привёл это "обрадован": *Я сплю, я ухожу, **я радуюсь**... — пассив (как его ни понимай) для таких глаголов исключен.*

Comment: Ответ следует удалить, как не содержащий значащей и полезной информации, а также как переполненный хамством и проявлением агрессией и неуважением к участнику, задавшему вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

[Ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/458675/178412), данный behemothus'ом выше, противоречив. Так, в первом абзаце сказано, что в русском «нету пассива», а уже во втором «своего рода 'пассив' появляется». Но эта придирка, конечно, схоластична.

Более существенно то, что behemothus без всяких ссылок и объяснений по теме делает сенсационное заявление об отсутствии пассива в русском языке. Это не соответствует действительности, если только не предусмотреть экзотичное определение залога.

Пассивный залог конечно же есть, см., например, иллюстрации из известной работы В. А. Плунгяна «Общая морфология» (М.:Ленанд, 2016):

> Все лингвисты, по-видимому, согласятся с тем, что залог — это то, что отличает друг от друга два следующих предложения:
>
> (1) а) *Большинство теоретиков отвергло этот аргумент.*
>        б) *Этот аргумент был отвергнут большинством теоретиков.*
>
> Более того, по-видимому, во всех описаниях предложение (1а) будет названо *активным*, а предложение (1b) — *пассивным*; соответственно, будет говориться о форме активного и пассивного залога глагола *отвергнуть*.

При всём уважение к behemothus'у в этом случае столь резкое отрицание факта описания языка невозможно принять.

Совершенно другое и гораздо более деликатное дело — это то, что в русском использование пассивных конструкций значительным образом ограничено (но все равно столь решительно говорить об отсутствии пассива **невозможно**).

---

Во-первых, заметна терминологическая путаница в вашем вопросе: вы называете *подлежащее* субъектом, а *дополнение* — объектом, хотя это термины разных сфер и обозначают далеко не всегда одно и то же. Например, в предложениях *Я побил Васю* и *Вася был побит мной* субъект один и тот же — *я*, равно как и объект — *Вася*. Нужно говорить **о разных подлежащих и сказуемых**.

Во-вторых, в своих примерах вы рассматриваете совершенно разные предложения:

> Я обучил Васю => Я был обучен Васей. Я обучился Васей.

Здесь безусловно возможна пассивная конструкция, которую легко образовать (быть + краткая форма страдательного причастия): *Я обучил Васю* = *Вася был обучен мной*. *Я был обучен Васей* имеет совершенно иной смысл!

Рассмотрим примеры, где, по-вашему, язык буксует:

1) *Я бью Васю => Я ??? Васей.* Здесь возможная пассивная конструкция *Вася избиваем мной*; приходится использовать глагол *избивать*, так как у *бить* нет нужной формы страд. прич. наст. вр. А конструкция возможна и грамматична, однако не употребительна.

2) *Я полюбил Васю => Вася был полюблен мной.*

3) *Прямая стала кривой => Прямая ??? кривой.* Глагол *стать* непереходный и не образует форм пассивного залога. Замена действительно невозможна.

Итак, выше мы рассмотрели некоторые причины, почему не всегда возможна замена активной конструкции пассивной.

P. S. В английском попытки построить пассивную конструкцию из активной не всегда удачны:

*Can you please buy a bar of chocolate? ≟ Can a bar of chocolate be bought by you?*

Comment: *...у бить нет нужной формы страд. прич. наст. вр.* — а как же "биваем"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой это, очевидно, форма итератива _бивать_.

Comment: Спасибо за поправки, во-многом с вами согласен. Только насчет моих конструкций поправочка:
"Я был обучен Васей имеет совершенно иной смысл!" Ну я так своеобразно сформулировал. Именно этот- мой смысл я и вкладывал в вопрос перехода из актива в пассив. То есть мы не имеем права менять подлежащее (а только лишь модифицировать глагол, не меняя его корень). При этом смысл обязан поменяться на противоположный. В ваших же примерах подлежащее меняется:  Вася избиваем мной. Я бью Васю. 
P.S.
Мне еще очень интересно, что означает фразы: I was slept ..., I was cost и тому подобные странные пассивы

Comment: @user190920 добавьте в текст вопроса тогда примеры тех конструкций в английском, аналоги которых вы хотите найти в русском. В текущем состоянии в примерах в вашем вопросе на каждой строке по два разных предложения, о чем я и пишу в ответе.

Comment: @Aer, абсолютно с вами согласен!