# Страдательный залог

Tags: глаголы

Как звучит слово "бояться" в страдательном залоге?

Comment: Никак. В русском языке у многих глаголов нет страдательного залога. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458665

Comment: устрашаемый, устрашенный)

Comment: Ну если можно менять глаголы, то пугать

Comment: Даже в английском такого нет.

Comment: @user190920 бояться от фобос - страх

Comment: стращаемый есть еще. А так, видимо, часть глаголов личные и не страдаются или стражаются

Comment: @user190920 насчет "пить, бить, мыть, шить, брать, ждать, писать" можно же с приставкой вы- вышитый, выбранный, выжданный, выпитый, ну и мытый, битый, шитый, писаный